# How to have Git auto-accept merge conflicts in untouched files properly

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I start by cutting a feature branch off of `master`. Lets say this branch is named `feature`. We also have a `development` branch which is currently 5 commits ahead of `master`.

When I finish my feature branch, I make it pretty so it's only 1 commit ahead of `master` (by rebasing using `git rebase -i HEAD~X`, where `X` is the number of commits I made), and then I merge it into `development` to test.

To do this, I use `git checkout development` and then `git merge --squash feature`. I see 10 merge conflicts. The files I changed on the `feature` I see in these conflicts, but I also get the changes of those 5 other commits (because `development` was already 5 commits ahead of `master`).

For an example, lets say I only modified file `A` on `feature`. When I perform the merge onto `development`, I see conflicts for files `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` (`B`-`D` being changes already existing on `development` which I don't have on `feature`).

I would like Git to auto-accept these merge conflicts (auto-accept current) in the files I did not touch (`B`, `C`, and `D`) and only show me conflicts in files I changed (`A`). Is this possible?

From the [Advanced merging section on git-scm](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging), I see that I can pass flags like `-Xours` and `-Xtheirs` while performing a merge, but it does not seem like I can apply them directly to files like how I want.

Comment: If after your interactive rebase squash into a single commit, your branch `feature` is only one commit ahead of `master`, and `development` is 5 commits ahead of `master`, then what's the point of `merge --squash`? (It's already one commit.) As for getting conflicts for files not in your single commit on feature- are you sure? If you accidentally included too many commits in your interactive rebase squash, you could potentially get conflicts on the merge. If you look at the all the changes in your 1 pretty commit, can you confirm the only changes are in `A`?

Comment: Assuming you are correct that `feature` has just one commit with changes only to `A`, try this command: `git log development..feature` (there are 2 dots there.) The result of that should only be your one commit on feature. If you get more than 1 commit, then something is amiss.